# Magento 2 bundle display out of stock product options

Tags: magento, magento2

i am playing with Bundle Items. i have few product option under bundle but when any product option goes out of stock then it goes away how i can show all options even product options goes out of stock.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior what you are seeing is expected. Though if you want as you mentioned, you can check with choosing 'no' for 'manage stock' option (Edit the bundle product -> Advanced inventory -> manage stock "no"). Though this is not recommended.